# Vue/JS: Accessing same variable within different class methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to put a lot of custom channel logic into it's own class.  In my `created` lifecycle method, I am calling each method in the class I created but how can I retain that instance of the `socket` I created in the init() method for use in the other methods?

**Main.vue**

```
import CustomClass from './CustomClass';

created() {

    const customClass = new CustomClass();
    customClass.init();
    customClass.subscribe();
}
```

**CustomClass.js**

```
import Socket from 'Socket';

class CustomClass {

    init() {
        const socket = new Socket(key: XXXXX);
    }
    subscribe() {
       // how to have access to `socket` here that was created in init?
        socket.subscribe(channel: 'xxxx');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the socket as a property on the class and access it using `this` keyword

```
import Socket from 'Socket';

class CustomClass {
  
  init() {
      // add the socket as a property on the CustomClass instance
      // it might be worth moving this to a constructor function

      this.socket = new Socket(key: XXXXX);
  }
  subscribe() {
     // access it by using `this` keyword
      this.socket.subscribe(channel: 'xxxx');
  }

}
```